# How to solve error while using Laravel 7 with livewire 1.0.13

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am trying to use Livewire 1.013 in my Laravel 7 application. I just installed livewire in my package. I am using xampp apache server. So, my project URL is like http://localhost/Projects/testproject/public .

When I do inspect the page that included with `@livewireStyles` and `@livewireScripts`, I am getting `net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)` error. I did `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=livewire:config` and added `@php artisan vendor:publish --force --tag=livewire:assets --ansi` in composer.json file. The I executed `composer dump-autoload` . The error still exists. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Instead of custom project URL, if I do PHP artisan ser with URL of `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` it works fine for me. But, in my case I have different project s and I have to use xampp apcahe.

Could you please help me to solve this?

Thanks in Advance !
Manu

Comment: Sounds like your projects root directory path in Apache is incorrect. You shouldn't have `public` in your url.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter: Other modules in laravel is working fine... for example my login path is http://localhost/Projects/testproject/public/login.. it shows login page... Only problem with livewire... I used public folder, because in apache, we have to click on project public folder to go to home page

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too. You can publish the Livewire config into your Laravel config directory:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=livewire:config
```

Then change the `asset_url` value in the `config/livewire` to the root or public directory of your app to something like this:

```
http://localhost/Projects/testproject/public
```